# Angular 5 Title service is undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, title

I try to change the page title with BrowserModule. I added the BrowserModule and Title in application module, like here: https://angular.io/guide/set-document-title

In a child module (I tried to add here the service and module (BrowserModule) too) I have a component where I insert the Title service, but that service is 'undefined'.

module

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { RouterModule, Routes } from "@angular/router";

import { ProductService } from "../../services/Product";

import { ProductComponent } from "../../components/product/component";
import { ProductResolve } from "../../components/product/resolve";

const routes: Routes =
[
    {
        path: "produs/:url",
        component: ProductComponent,
        resolve:
        {
            Product: ProductResolve,
        },
    },
];

@NgModule({
    imports:
    [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    ],
    providers:
    [
        ProductResolve,
        ProductService,
    ],
    declarations:
    [
        ProductComponent,
    ],
    exports:
    [
        RouterModule,
        ProductComponent,
    ],
})
export class ProductModule { }
```

component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from "@angular/core";
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
import { Product } from "../../services/Product";
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
    templateUrl: "../../templates/product/component.html",
    styleUrls: [
        "../../sass/product/component.scss",
    ]
})

export class ProductComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy
{
    private Subscribe: any;

    constructor(private titleService: Title, private Route: ActivatedRoute)
    {

    }

    ngOnInit()
    {
        this.Subscribe = this.Route.data.subscribe(this.process);
    }

    private process(product: Product)
    {
        //console.log(this.title);

        //this.titleService.setTitle(product.Title);
    }

    ngOnDestroy()
    {
        this.Subscribe.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

app module

```
import { BrowserModule, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
...

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ...
    ],
    imports: [
        ...
        BrowserModule,

    ],
    providers: [LoadingScreenService, Title],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: @ConnorsFan did this, still undefined

Comment: Can we get the exact error message?

Comment: When I try to use this.titleService.setTitle('test'); I got that this.titleService is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are losing the scope.
In the `process()` scope `this` doesn't represent your class instance anymore.

Adding `.bind(this)` should solve your problem.

```
this.Subscribe = this.Route.data.subscribe(this.process.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is a common one: when a class method is used as a callback function, `this` is incorrect inside of the method. You should use an arrow function as the callback:

```
this.Subscribe = this.Route.data.subscribe((product: Product) => {
    this.process(product);
});
```